# Search by post title and content in wp_query without order

Tags: posts, wp-query

I am trying to do a search engine, I am using get_posts () function with parameter 's'. It finds me post by title and content but in a disorderly way, how could I tell it to first consult the titles and then put at the end the post whose content is what I am looking for?

```
   $query = array(
        'post_type' => 'tacos',
        'showposts' => 999,
        'posts_per_page' => 999,
    );

    $query['s'] = "Fish";

    $items = get_posts($query);
    $posts = array();

    foreach ($items as $position => $item) {...
```

This print the result of post with title and content that contains "Fish" but without order. I would like to put first title post and finally, the post with the content.

I finally solve it using specific sql query:

```
    global $wpdb;
    
    $query="SELECT 
    ID,
    post_title 
FROM $wpdb->posts
WHERE (`post_title`LIKE '%".$wpdb->esc_like($search)."%' OR `post_content`LIKE '%".$wpdb->esc_like($search)."%') AND `post_type`='page'
ORDER BY case
        when `post_title`LIKE '%".$wpdb->esc_like($search)."%' then 0
        when `post_content`LIKE '%".$wpdb->esc_like($search)."%' then 1
    END, post_title";

     $postid=$wpdb->get_results($query,'ARRAY_A');
```

Comment: I resolve it using custom sql query to wordpress database: